# Angular Factory Object binded to Scope not appearing in Modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-services

I'm trying to pass information about a listing that appears on the show page to the modal on that page.

I successfully created the factory service which returns me an object.

```
angular.module('articles').factory('ProductService', [ '$resource', 'Articles','$stateParams', function($resource, Articles, $stateParams) {
    var listingInfo = 
        Articles.get({
        articleId: $stateParams.articleId
      });
        return listingInfo;
    }
]);
```

(logged by using `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('ProductService')`)

If I place this in my main `ArticlesController` I'm able to see the scope via browser console with `angular.element($0).scope()` and able to access the object by injecting into my controller and giving it a scope of `$scope.product = ProductService;`, allowing me to access the data in the expected way (`product.furtherinfo`).

However when trying the same technique for my modal controllers, I'm unable to find the scope when I log through the browser or access the data through binding or brackets.

I've tried passing the value through the resolve, injecting the dependency in all my controllers having to do with my modal, but nothing works.

```
// Modals
angular.module('articles').controller('ModalDemoCtrl',['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'ProductService' , function ($scope, $modal, $log, ProductService) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.product = ProductService;

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        },
        product: function () {
          return $scope.product;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

}]);
```

The idea is to pass the returned factory object to my modal so I can link it to an input(maybe hidden) that I could designate as a model to send through to an email.

```
angular.module('articles').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'items', '$http', 'product','ProductService','$stateParams', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, $http, product,ProductService,$stateParams) {
$scope.items = items;
$scope.product = product;
$scope.sendMail = function(){
var data = ({
      input : this.contactAgentInput,
      inputBody : this.contactAgentInputBody,
    }) 

    $http.post('/contact-agent', data).
    then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);

    console.log("all is well")
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  })
  }
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
}]);
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? ProductService is being injected into your modal directly. Please make your question more concise.

Comment: I would like to access my ProductService object within my modal. So I can autofill the value of my modal inputs with that listings information. Example `<input value='product.address'>` would give me the address that is seen on the show page. Hope I'm being clear, I'll elaborate if not.

Comment: You're injecting `ProductService` into `ModalInstanceCtrl`. Why don't you use it?

Comment: @AnidMonsur tried to access it by just injecting ProductService, but my attempts to use it failed. And when I logged the modal to see it's scopes using `angular.element($0).scope()` I didn't see the `$scope.product` listed in the console, leading me to believe it wasn't injected/ passed successfully.

Comment: Use a debugger or `console.log`. If you add `console.log(ProductService)` in your modal controller, it should show you the service is being injected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AnidMonsur i noticed my Rentals controller firing off while In the Sales show page (I split the modules into Sales and Rentals). Thinking that I might be launching the modal from the wrong Module. Investigating now.

Comment: @AnidMonsur that did it! I was using the same names for some of the modal controllers ( stupid obviously) it must have launched the wrong modal instance and that's why I wasn't able to access the object. After giving them distinct names, it now works. Thanks so much, would have spent another day overlooking the error!

Comment: Have a look at this plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/HvI1hVFLoWnxke6XkFMV?p=preview). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a debugger or console.log. If you add console.log(ProductService) in your modal controller, it should show you the service is being injected. –  Anid Monsur

Thanks for the suggestion @AnidMonsur i noticed my Rentals controller       firing off while In the Sales show page (I split the modules into Sales and Rentals). Thinking that I might be launching the modal from the wrong Module. Investigating now. –  Meir Snyder

@AnidMonsur that did it! I was using the same names for some of the modal controllers ( stupid obviously) it must have launched the wrong modal instance and that's why I wasn't able to access the object. After giving them distinct names, it now works. Thanks so much, would have spent another day overlooking the error! –  Meir Snyder

Answer (score -1):

Let me guess. You're trying to display the items in the ModalDemoCtrl through the ModalInstanceCtrl, but you can't.

It seems you think DI is going to work as long as you put the name of the dependency but it's not until you register the dependency itself. So 'items' won't ever be a dependency at all and all you get is the value in the inner $scope on the controller (which probrablly is undefined).

In your case I'd say you register a third party factory (which is closer to a singleton) which can be injected just alike ProductService, and eventually would be called ItemsFactory.

Hope it helped.

Comment: He does have `items` registered. It's resolved by ui-bootstrap's $modal service.

Comment: I'm not using the items at all, I just left it in the code to illustrate how I was trying to pass my ProductService through in different ways. Found the suggestion of trying to pass it through the resolve method in another stack question, thought that method might work, just wrong implementation, so I left it in.

Comment: Question edited while I was posting. Tho I didn't see the resolve method, my bad.